# Remove null duplicates in Table

Tags: mysql, sql

My `table` looks like this:

```
rank   cost    segment      description
 1       23      pen         2mm red pen
 2       22      pen         3mm red pen
 3       10      pen         4mm green pen
 3               pen                       
 4               pen         5mm red pen
 5               pen         1 mm yellow pen
 1       3      eraser       red eraser
 2       2      eraser       red eraser
 3       5      eraser       green eraser
 4              eraser
 4       6      eraser       red eraser
 5              eraser       yellow eraser
```

Need to convert into:

```
 rank   cost    segment         description
     1       23      pen         2mm red pen
     2       22      pen         3mm red pen
     3       10      pen         4mm green pen
     4               pen         5mm red pen
     5               pen         1 mm yellow pen
     1       3      eraser        red eraser       
     2       2      eraser        red eraser
     3       5      eraser        green eraser
     4       6      eraser        red eraser
     5              eraser        yellow eraser
```

`Note`: Empty `rank 3` from segment `pen` and `rank 4` from segment `eraser` gets removed.

I have been trying to achieve this using `select * from table where cost!=0`
but in this case `rank 5` gets removed as well because it is empty. Which is not desired.

I want to keep all the ranks even if its empty in each segment, just want to remove that duplicate rank in a segment which has empty `cost` value.

I tried several other ways to achieve this but failed. Is there any better way to achieve this? May be I need to use `group by segment` or any `duplicate` keyword, if there is any?

Apologies for such a novice question.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregation seems to do what you want:

```
select rank, sum(cost) as cost, segment, max(description)
from t
group by rank, segment;
```

This returns one row per `segment`/`rank` combination in the data.

Comment: And if I have multiple numerical and categorical columns in the table do I mention all the name of the columns in the `select` statement and put aggregation function to each column except `rank` and `segment`?

Comment: @user9645175 . . . Yes.  That is a viable approach, particularly if you are working with just two duplicates.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will apply this on my real table. And then mark your answer as correct! :) But I was wondering what aggregation function to put on the rest of the columns? `max()` will be okay for rest of my categorical and numerical column?

Comment: @user9645175 . . . `max()` is fine for basically all data types.

Comment: And your solution solved my problem like a magic!! Thanks a million :)